# Server Error 403 Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document

Tags: javascript, server, hosting, plesk

I uploaded a ready-made website template using filezilla. I encountered an error in the header when I entered the site. What should I do?
i use windows hosting and plesk panel

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 403 error is a very generic permissions problem error. It could be a misconfiguration, a file permissions problem, an authentication problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you had probably uploaded template with a root connection, these permision doesn't authorize web client to see files owned by root.

You may use dedicated FTP client for uploading files or checking files/directory owners.

Fixing it on Linux servers by SSH root command:
chown -R edipcan:psaserv /var/www/vhosts/yourdomainname.com/httpdocs/*

Solvig this for Windows : you can use Plesk File Manager
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213407189-How-to-manage-file-directory-permissions-via-Plesk-File-Manager

Answer (score 0):

Another problem may arise that I have been faced and solved with the following.

(1) if your domain "https://..." https showing 'not secured' or 'certificate is not valid' then the browsers wouldn't let you access website resources like: files, images links.

(2) You can run website by clicking browsers safe options but can't access resources unless you valid certified your "https://..." protocol.